# Spring MVC with AngularJS get data

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I have an object I can access in the .jsp file using the syntax ${items} which is actually just a JSTL JSON object from a GET mapped to a page called items. Is there a way to get and parse this data using AngularJS and have it ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render the object as a JavaScript variable assignment in a script block on the page.  Then access it via said variable in JavaScript.  Assuming `${items}` renders as JSON:

```
<script>
    var myGlobalData = ${items};
</script>
```

Comment: this helped! since the data I am getting is a JSON, I could just create a model in the scope like $scope.items = myGlobalData;